# 'module' object not callable (Hexchat Plugin)

Tags: python, callable, hexchat

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 23, in isdown
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Not sure what's going on here. I'm very new to Python scripting.

(This is for an IRC client called Hexchat. If you need the whole script, please let me know.)

Comment: That means that you attempted to call the thing you just imported: `your_imported_module()`

Comment: How would I fix this? Here's the full script: http://pastebin.com/kL0xYp3M

Comment: I think the problem is in `urllib.request (link)`, because `urllib.request` is a module in standard library. If you want to use some function from this module do `urllib.request.somefunction(link)`